# A word for the circular guides that determine the curve of font serifs?

Tags: terminology, typography, obscure-terms

Serif fonts are usually constructed using circular guides to establish the curves of the serifs.

Example:

[image: serif font construction / blueprint]

Is there a word for these circles?

Comment: Please cite the source of the figure.